# Redirect output of tar command to a variable in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, tar

I am untaring a .tar.gz file and redirecting the output to a variable. But it gives me an error while doing this operation.

```
old_file =$(tar -tvzf $node | head -2 | tail -1 | cut -f4 -d "/")
```

Error:

```
 old_file: command not found
```

But if run this command in terminal I am getting some output.

Unable to figure out, if tar file redirection works or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be `old_file=$(some cmd)`. No space between variable and '='.

Answer (score 0):

could you try this;

```
old_file =$(tar -tvzf $node | head -2 | tail -1 | cut -f3 -d "/")
```

Eg;

tar -tvzf $node | head -2 | tail -1  output is something like this;

```
-rw-rw-r-- user/user     2 2016-11-07 12:10 yourfile/php.png
```

cut fields are as below, if delimiter is "/";

field 1 is   `-rw-rw-r-- user`

field 2 is    `user     2 2016-11-07 12:10 yourfile`

field 3 is     `php.png`